# difference between atjobs & atspool directory

Tags: 12.04, cron

when i was working with ubuntu 12.04 **at** command i noticed that there are two different directories **/var/spool/cron/atspool** and **/var/spool/cron/atjobs** . I want to know what is the difference between these two directories. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

`man atd` states:

```
/var/spool/cron/atjobs The directory for storing jobs;
this should be mode 700, owner daemon.

/var/spool/cron/atspool The directory for storing output;
this should be mode 700, owner daemon.
```

So the actual job is saved in atjobs and the output (if any) of such jobs is stored in atspool.

Comment: what output? errors?

Comment: No errors with atd are by default logged to syslog (the -d option debugs to screen instead of syslog). Example would be "mails".

Comment: any example will you give me please?

Comment: while the at job is running its output is temporarily stored in a file in the atspool directory. once the job finishes, it emails the output via sendmail, then deletes the file it made in the atspool directory. so for example if your job is "echo echo hello | at now", the atspool directory will briefly hold a file with the content: "hello" in it.